# Customize Power BI reports in D365 for Finance and Operations

Tags: powerbi, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I've extended `CustInvoiceTrans` table by one custom field, now I wanted to show that field in "Sales and Profitability Performance" Power BI embedd report in D365 FO.  I found that this report is using "SALESCUBE" aggregate measurement and there is no way to extend this.

This "SalesCube" aggregate measurement is using `CustInvoiceTransExpended` view so I've added my custom field to this View but couldn't able to get this on aggregate measurement or Sales and Profitability Performance power BI report?

Can anyone please suggest how to add that custom field?

Comment: As far as I know, you are correct, there is currently no way to extend these objects. What you can try is to copy them and then modify the copies.

Comment: @FH-Inway - Then how can those changes will be visible on original report if I do changes by copying them??